# Why does my text field does net appear in the centre?

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I am building a website for a project at college but somehow I do not get the paragraph aligned in the centre on the top of the webpage.

I tried inline, but that did not work, then I tried CSS, but it still does not work the way I want it to:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    left: -250;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #042331;
}

.sidebar header {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 70px;
    background: #063146;
    user-select: none;
}

.sidebar ul a{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 65px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    transition: .4s;
}

ul li:hover a{
    padding-left: 50px;
}

.sidebar ul a i{
    margin-right: 16px;
}

.welcome1{
    text-align: center;
    color: white; 
    background-color: #063146;
}
```

This is the html markup:

```css
.sidebar {
        position: fixed;
        left: -250;
        width: 250px;
        height: 100%;
        background: #042331;
    }
.sidebar header {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 70px;
    background: #063146;
    user-select: none;
}
.sidebar ul a{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 65px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    transition: .4s;
}
ul li:hover a{
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.sidebar ul a i{
    margin-right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="eng" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>side-menu bar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/55138bdcbe.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="sidebar1.jpg" style="height: 100px; width : 250px" alt="">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <header>Traning-App Navigator</header>
            <ul>
                <li><a hrf="homepage.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>  Home</a></li>
                <li><a hrf="project.html"><i class="fas fa-brush"></i> Project</a></li>
                <li><a hrf="aboutus.html"><i class="far fa-question-circle"></i> About us</a></li>
                <li><a hrf="contact.html"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a></li>
                
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="welcome1">  <p>
            here you will find everything you will need for your Training such as nutriënts, schematics, advice on training exercises and alike!
            so if you are ready to start your training journey... then let us guide you through it!
            </p></div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

But when I save it and try to use it the code just does not seem to do what it should. Do you have any solutions to this problem?

Comment: youre going to have to give us your relevant html to see what you're actually having a problem with

Comment: Try using flex box... Justify content center and align items center.... Share the reproducible html code and expected result

Comment: What text box? What paragraph? (Which is it, you seem to have changed your mind between the title and the first paragraph of the question). You've provided a *lot* of CSS and no HTML. Provide a [mcve] and use the [live demo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) feature of the question editor.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:web-site-project]? Are you really using that "strange" feature of Visual Studio? Please pay attention to the tags applied to your question.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If welcome1 is your paragraph you have 2 choices.</strike>

```css
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
```

Or

```css
display:grid;
place-items:center;
```

Without seeing the html, this is the best recommendation that can be given

After review of HTML:
It can be noted that the major problem is that your side bar is set to fixed and this makes it no longer inline with the welcome div therefor the welcome div is returning to take up the whole space.
an idea fix is listed below

```css
.sidebar{
position: fixed;
left: 0;
}

.welcome1{
width: 100%;
margin-left: 250px;
}
```

This minor change should give room for your div to scroll down and for text to be centered within that div and will take up 100% of the left over space post applying the `margin-left`.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the `<div>` with the paragraph to the top of the code. That fixes the display order. I also added:

```
p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

I guess you meant that by centering.

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: -250;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #042331;
}

.sidebar header {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: #063146;
  user-select: none;
}

.sidebar ul a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 65px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  transition: .4s;
}

ul li:hover a {
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.sidebar ul a i {
  margin-right: 16px;
}

p {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="eng" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>side-menu bar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/55138bdcbe.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="sidebar1.jpg" style="height: 100px; width : 250px" alt="">
  <div class="welcome1">
    <p>
      here you will find everything you will need for your Training such as nutriënts, schematics, advice on training exercises and alike! so if you are ready to start your training journey... then let us guide you through it!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <header>Traning-App Navigator</header>
    <ul>
      <li><a hrf="homepage.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>  Home</a></li>
      <li><a hrf="project.html"><i class="fas fa-brush"></i> Project</a></li>
      <li><a hrf="aboutus.html"><i class="far fa-question-circle"></i> About us</a></li>
      <li><a hrf="contact.html"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I you don't want the text to take up the entire width of the page though, then you can use:

```
    p {
      max-width: 500px; /* The maximal width for your text. 
      Don't use normal width, because if the viewport is smaller than the width you set, there will be overflow. */
      margin: auto;
      text-align: center;
    }
```